# liquibase double type with precision

Tags: mysql, double, liquibase, changelog

I have a problem with a ChangeLog file. I have a lot of columns in my mySQL Database with a DOUBLE type (DOUBLE(22)). For example: .
I use this command for generating changelog file (command line):

```
./liquibase --defaultsFile=liquibase.properties generateChangeLog
```

where liquibase.properties is like tenter code herechangeLogFile: ./structure.xml

When I execute the update command, I have an error, because I have a wrong type (DOUBLE 22 instead of DOUBLE).

How can I fix this (with command line options)?

Kind Regards

Answer (score 1):

This is fixed for Liquibase 3.4.1 https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-2414